# Javascript loop for HTML template

Tags: javascript, ejs, html-templates

I am building a list of items using a single `JSON` where several items have a common `key:value` pair and are sorted and clubbed together.  The need is to make a header above the clubbed section using the common valued key-value pair. And then wrap the list items as per groups with the heading between group.

While most of the logic is written, the only thing that I am unable to implement is the closing `DIV` for the clubbed section `.table-wrp`.

This is the link to the codepen: https://codepen.io/nitinsuri/pen/OJgbXZN.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: What exactly is the desired result? You want a menu above the table or something?

Comment: The other thing is tables are nested in side of each other, which I am assuming is incorrect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up recreating this with my own vision of what it 'should' look like (and apologies for the poor styling).

My main additions are as follows.

1. Getting a unique array of regions, since that is how we plan on segregating the array of items.

```
const uniqueRegions = [...new Set(bridgesListData.map(({region})=>region))].sort()
```

2. Next, based on the region you are in, you can retrieve the relevant items:

```
const itemsByRegion = (array, region) => {
  return bridgesListData.filter((item)=>item.region === region)
}
```

Simply pass the function expression the array and region in question and you will have the items you want.

3. Although it needs some styling help, the table can be displayed using a couple of `forEach` loops (I really don't like using a `for` loop because of how much additional complexities (vs benefits) it introduces.

```
let template = `<% uniqueRegions.forEach(region => {
 %> 
  <h1><%= region %></h1>
  <table>
  <thead>
   <tr>
    <th style="border-bottom: solid 1px black;">Truss Type</th>   
    <th style="border-bottom: solid 1px black;">Location</th>
    <th style="border-bottom: solid 1px black;">Year</th>
   </tr> 
   <thead>
   <tbody>
   <% itemsByRegion(bridgesListData, region).forEach(item => {
   %>
    <tr>
     <th><%= item.trussType %></th>
     <th><%= item.nameLocation %></th>
     <th><%= item.year %></th>
    </tr> <%
   }) %>
   </tbody>
  </table>
 <%}) %>`;
```

I hope I understood your requirements [here](https://codepen.io/riza-khan/pen/RwgoQjJ?editors=0011).